# how send put requests in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart, flutter-android

I am trying to update my json list on https://app.jsonstorage.net/

but i got response code 415 here is my code:

[image]

and this is my json on jsonstorage:

```
[{"username": "Amirhossein", "password": "302940101692", "email": "sahosseini1382@gmail.com", "phone": "09944236807"},{"username": "Hosna", "password": "74610945", "email": "hosseiniamir71@gmail.com", "phone": "09353792083"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a header to your request:

```
Response resPut = await put (postur1, 
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
        "email": email,
        "phone": phone
        },
    headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json"
        }
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code 415 means "*Unsupported Media Type*", and if you're getting that back it means you're successfully *sending* a put request to that URL, but with the wrong content type. Adding the following headers should resolve the issue:

```dart
Response resPut = await put(postUrl, 
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
        "email": email,
        "phone": phone,
    },
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
    },
));
```

If the error still occurs, I suggest that you read the documentation of the API you are consuming to see what you need to send.